# Broadcast Notification to multiple users at the same time - PHP/MySql/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, notifications

I'm new to the forum, any advise is appreciated I've search a lot and read and read a lot of topics to find the best way for my project I'll get straight to the point

I'm building a Broadcast site to be used internally at work using wamp server (intranet).

Languages used: PHP, JS, Ajax, MySql

For the moment we are using a chat system (spark), but the idea of the project is to keep broadcasts records and it's easier to track

Please don't offer me Third party applications/tools

I have a simple html form that a user submit info, consider this example.

Form: title (input text field), Broadcast message(input text field)

Info stored in the db table:

bc_id, title, bc_msg, submitted_by, date_time

Another table user_got_bc: user_id, bc_id, bc_sent (0 default), once notification is sent, the value is 1

I'm using ajax to look in the "user_got_bc" table and verify which user has the bc_sent = 0 and send a notification to him with the bc info from the other table, then update the value of the bc_sent to 1

The ajax code is executed every 10000 ms using setinterveral

once a user submit a broadcast I want all other USERS (PLURAL) to receive a notification AT THE SAME TIME (a second less or more is ok)

Now regarding the Notification, you don't have to worry about that, i'm using Desktop notification (webkitnotification), I know it's not cross browser compatible, but it doesn't matter and it's working fine

That said, everything is working fine

My worries are the number of connections the ajax code will do to the server if this good or bad, the more the users, the more the connections

I know it won't be good to bombard the server with that amount of connections, specially since it's every 10 secs x the number of users

I read on many forums to use comets, from what i gathered it's not friendly with PHP, plus i've never implemented that before

So my questions are: - is there a better way or keep it the way is set up is fine? - if comets is better, is it possible to provide a snippet to work for that project?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: If it already works, why bother? Do you have a real performance problem? Also, since the calls are triggered from the client side, they won't come in at exactly the same time. All in all, I wouldn't invest much time, unless you have a real problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's working fine, you're right they aren't triggered at the same time, and it's working flawless, just wanted to get others opinion

Answer (score 0):

Please google for Ajax long polling. But for this kind of project i suggest using
some realtime i/o software like

[node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

If you have good JavaScript skills then you should not have problem in using above listed
apps. If your project is going to have more number of users then you will require PUB-SUB, Realtime, Cross Browser Socket support. Finally a PUSH technology. Where above listed apps have all this features. So give a try.

If you still want to stick to PHP, JS, Ajax, MySql then you may require Ajax long polling technique.